# Going to do (simple) change in local copy of jquery. Please suggest if any drawbacks are possible

Tags: jquery, sizzle

I writing a html page that should "run" in quite special environment (have some limitations that is not present in regular browser). Need to say that environment is based on version of IE that is currently available in OS. Also I have to support IE8, but some UI degradation is OK.

I would like to use jquery lib in it but loading of it causes appearance of messagebox with next text

> Microsoft JScript runtime error
>
> Permission denied

I had a couple of digging sessions and after last one found an exact line of jquery source where it occurs. next (sub)expression causes it

```
rnative.test( docElem.contains )
```

its located on [line #1286 of jquery](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/0d5ec2d8ac94a419ee47a39319c43ff9a7326b50/dist/jquery.js#L1286). "eval" of that code gives next expression

```
/^[^{]+\{\s*\[native \w/.test(document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].contains)
```

my best idea is to replace that expression with following

```
/*rnative.test( docElem.contains )*/false
```

So my queston is next: What issues I may get with this change?

PS: its not a 1st April joke :(

Comment: What version of jQuery are you modifying?

Comment: latest that supports IE8 - 1.11.1

upd: I missed that there is 1.11.2..

Comment: i would open a bug with them.

Comment: env is **very custom and rare**. I am not sure if they will consider it due to this